# How to determine if exclusive open will succeed in foxpro?

Tags: foxpro

If I attempt to gain an exclusive table open in FoxPro, it generates a dialog  box if access is denied.  Since I'm targeting an non-interactive application, is there a way to detect whether the operation will succeed, or at least have it fail silently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have VFP 8 or greater:

```
TRY
    USE MyTable IN 0 EXCLUSIVE
ENDTRY
...
IF USED ("MyTable")
    *-- Use the table here
ENDIF
```

Comment: Just found that.  However, I found that I needed an (empty) CATCH statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, table-opens are one of those "it could fail softly but we made it fail hard" operations.  The TRY-CATCH-ENDTRY or ON ERROR arrangements are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For older versions:

```
cOldError = ON("ERROR")
ON ERROR *
USE MyTable IN 0 EXCLUSIVE
lSuccess = used("MyTable")
ON ERROR &cOldError

if lSuccess ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using FOPEN...

```
nFHdl = FOPEN("myfile.dbf", 1)  &&  1 tries to open the file for writing
IF nFHdl > 0 THEN
   FCLOSE(nFHdl)
   USE myfile.dbf exclusive
ELSE
   = messagebox("Can't open Exclusive")
ENDIF
```